# How to find locations of multiple elements in an array in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Here is my code in Julia. I want to find locations of elements of array b in array a.

```
a = [2,4,1,3]
b = [1,4]
c=[]
for i in 1:length(b)
    push!(c, findfirst(isequal(b[i]), a));
end
println(c)
```

The result is [3, 2]. It's correct. But I believe there should be a more Julian (efficient) approach. 
I tried

```
julia> findall(x -> x == b, a)
0-element Array{Int64,1}
```

It's wrong.
Then

```
julia> findall(x -> x == .b, a)
ERROR: syntax: invalid identifier name "."
```

or

```
julia> findall(x -> x .== b, a)
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (BitArray{1}) used in boolean context
```

The following result is wrong!

```
julia> findall(x -> x in b, a)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
```

I think it considered 'b' as a set and ignored the sequence of elements in 'b'. I want the correct sequence [3,2].
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Your original solution is very much Julian. But you should almost never write `c = []`, since that creates a vector of `Any`. Write `c = Int[]` instead.

Comment: Note that `a` is long and `b` contains more than just a few elements, it will be much more efficient you sort the elements of `a` and use binary search with `searchsorted`. Of course in this scenario you can buffer location indices to come back to original indexes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`indexin`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.indexin):

```
julia> a = [2,4,1,3]; b = [1,4];

julia> indexin(b, a)
2-element Array{Union{Nothing, Int64},1}:
 3
 2
```

However, don't be afraid of `for`-loops as in your first example, they are very readable and often as efficient (if not more) as built-in methods like `indexin`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and nice answer. I tested that Array{Union{Nothing, Int64},1} behaves similar to Array{Int64,1}. That's good.

Answer (score 4):

`indexin` is probably the right solution, but what you were trying to do is probably

```
julia> findfirst.(.==(b), (a,))
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 2
```

The difference from `indexin` is that this will return an `Array{Int64,1}` if all elements are found, while `indexin` returns an `Array{Union{Nothing, Int64},1}` either way.

Comment: Thank you, DNF. That's an interesting answer.